# AWS CLI command to list stopped instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

```
ec2-describe-instances --filter "instance-state-name=stopped"
```

This helps me list all stopped instances with all its details.
How should I modify the command that it only gives me the names of the stopped instances?

Comment: These days, it is recommended that you use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using old style commands. Use `AWS CLI` to get what you want.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters  "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]'
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

you can use aws cli combined with other tools like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped \
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{ID: InstanceId,Hostname: PublicDnsName,Name: Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value }' \
| jq '.[] | .Name[]'
```

this will produce output in form:

```
"instance2"
"instance1"
```